# Remapping F1 on vim-gnome

Tags: key-bindings, linux

I want to use <kbd>F1</kbd> in vim-gnome* on Ubuntu 14.04.2.  But when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> I get Gnome "help". It's stopping me from remapping <kbd>F1</kbd> to something useful.

Searching reveals that the trick is to use dconf to map <kbd>F1</kbd> to something else, but this doesn't work for me; it stops the help window from appearing but Gnome still seems to be stealing the key before Vim sees it.

*: I've installed `vim-gnome` because that's what you have to do if you want support for clipboard but can't be bothered building Vim from source.

Comment: No need to justify yourself: vim-gnome *is* the only package worth installing on Ubuntu.

Comment: `nnoremap <F1> :echo "something useful"<CR>` works perfectly without doing anything weird.

Comment: Apparently Neovim is only going to ship with the one, full version - none of this cut-down nonsense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think gnome and the gnome-terminal intercept the keypresses, so that those keys never get through to Vim. [This answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/244786) shows how to disable this specifically for gnome and the gnome-terminal.